# Loading JSON from HTTP little by little (on pieces)

Tags: android, json, listview, download

I think this post is not on StackOverflow for Android's topic, so if it is, I'm sorry, but I've searched for it a lot.

**My question**

I was looking for an endless listview populating method, like Android Market's do, and I [found it, which is great](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless).

The thing is: I'm downloading a 5 MB JSON file of only strings and entries of my `ListView`

I don't want to make the user to wait until the JSON file is downloaded, so I want to show the first entries, so I would have to download my JSON file in pieces or parts... **how could I do it?**

1. **This is how I download my file:**
       public class lista extends AsyncTask {

   ```
       @Override
       protected void onPreExecute() {
       pd = new ProgressDialog(inscritos.this);
       pd.setTitle("Procesando...");
       pd.setMessage("Espera hasta que se termine.");
       pd.setCancelable(false);
       pd.setIndeterminate(true);
       pd.show();
       }

       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(final String... params) {
           InputStream source = f.retrieveStream(params[0]);
           Gson gson = new Gson();
           Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);

           Respuesta response = gson.fromJson(reader, Respuesta.class);
           Socio[] socios = response.getSocio();

           lista = new ArrayList<Socio>();
           for (Socio o : socios) {
               lista.add(o);
           }
           return null;

       }


       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(final Void result) {
           pd.dismiss();
       }
   }
   ```
2. **This is how I **retrieve my stream*** (`f.retrieveStream(params[0]))`)*

   ```
       @SuppressLint("NewApi")

   public static InputStream retrieveStream(String url) {

   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
       StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
       StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
   }

   DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

   HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

   try {

       HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
       final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

       if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
           Log.w("ERROR", "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url);
           return null;
       }

       HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
       return getResponseEntity.getContent();

   } catch (IOException e) {
       getRequest.abort();
       Log.w("ERROR", "Error for URL " + url, e);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       getRequest.abort();
       Log.w("ERROR", "Error for URL " + url, e);
   }
   return null;}
   ```

Thank you

Comment: I think you should reconsider your design. Both a user and a device will almost certainly have a tough time digesting so much data. But just for the user experience, could you consider a paging or faceting approach?

Comment: The thing is that I can not load a list until it's downloaded, so as @Abhished V said, it's a webservice work, not mine.

Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Well, he suggests paging as I did, and of course paging would happen on the server. I'm glad we all agree haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it should be implemented at the **Server side**(Ex : your php script), not at the client side. Write your php script such that it gives response based on the **offset** and **limit** requested by the client. Let's say if you want 10 entries starting from `index 0`, then `offset` should be `0` and `limit` should be `10`. Based on that `offset` and `limit` your json response should contain only so much data.

If you are using `php` at the server side, Here is a nice tutorial about using paging through php

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm

Comment: I really was expecting this response, but as I'm very optimist I tried to ask to see the experience of other users in StackOverflow for making it from the client.

Thanks a lot =)